# Refactor React class component into functional with hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am revisiting a project that I did 3 years ago. I would like to refactor it to use only functional components with hooks, if possible. At least, I want to get rid of the now UNSAFE lifecycle methods such as componentWillReceiveProps and componentWillMount.

First code below is the (shortened where you see ..) starting point, second piece of code is what I have so far. The bit I am struggling with is how to access nextProps without componentWillReceiveProps? I understand that some use of useEffect must be the answer, but how to use it is eluding me. Anyone able to help please? If someone could show the code as they would write it, given my objective that would be great! If you need to see any other code mentioned, I will add. Thanks.

Starting code:

```
class AddEducation extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      school: '',
      ..,
      errors: {},
      disabled: false,
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.onCheck = this.onCheck.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({ errors: nextProps.errors });
    }
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const eduData = {
      school: this.state.school,
      ..,
    };

    this.props.addEducation(eduData, this.props.history);
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="add-education">
        ..
              <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <TextFieldGroup
                  placeholder="* School"
                  name="school"
                  value={this.state.school}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  error={errors.school}
                />
                ..
              </form>
            ..
      </div>
    );
  }
}

AddEducation.propTypes = {
  addEducation: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  profile: state.profile,
  errors: state.errors,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addEducation })(
  withRouter(AddEducation)
);
```

What I have so far:

```
function AddEducation(props) {
  const [eduState, setEduState] = useState({
    school: '',
    ..,
  });

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const eduData = {
      school: eduState.school,
      degree: eduState.degree,
      fieldofstudy: eduState.fieldofstudy,
      from: eduState.from,
      to: eduState.to,
      current: eduState.current,
      description: eduState.description,
    };

    props.addEducation(eduData, props.history);
  };

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setEduState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  useEffect(
    (props.errors) => {setEduState({ errors: props.errors });
    },
    [eduState.errors]
  );

  const { errors } = eduState;

  return (
    <div className="add-education">
      ..
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
              <TextFieldGroup
                placeholder="* School"
                name="school"
                value={eduState.school}
                onChange={onChange}
                error={errors.school}
              />
              ..
              </form>
            ..
    </div>
  );
}

AddEducation.propTypes = {
  addEducation: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  profile: state.profile,
  errors: state.errors,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addEducation })(
  withRouter(AddEducation)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments:

1. You should avoid copying props to the state (see [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#anti-pattern-unconditionally-copying-props-to-state)). You can just use the `errors` from your props instead
2. If you still need to copy them, you can utilize the fact that when working with hooks you can have many "states". In this case you can just store them in a piece of state called `errors`:

   ```
   const [errors, setErrors] = useState()
   ```
3. Your effect should then look like this:

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
      setErrors(props.errors)
   }, [props.errors])
   ```

Comment: Thanks, it is almost working now. I used the code in point 3. The errors do get set and show up under the relevant form inputs as desired. But, when the form is successfully submitted, they do not clear from the state. I added a return in useEffect - so code used is now useEffect(() => {
    setErrors(props.errors);
    return () => setErrors({});
  }, [props.errors]);   I expected the return to run when the form is submitted and the page changes to a different page. Any idea how to resolve?

Comment: Also, I just tried removing the return function in useEffect, and adding setErrors({}) at the top of the onSubmit function. Still the errors do not reset to empty object. Could it be something to do with using an object of errors, rather than a single string for example?

Comment: The effect syncs the errors from the props with the state. Try clearing the errors that are coming in via the props

Comment: I realise that useEffect is putting the errors from the props into state. How would I clear the errors coming in thru the props? Basically, I think what I need to do is simply clear errors from state whenever the page is navigated to, but I am at a loss how to accomplish this.

Comment: how do the errors get into the props? Looks like you are using redux, so to clear the errors you would dispatch some redux action

Comment: You're right, using redux. But the component in question is rendered on a page that is served by react-router (via a Link element). No props are passed to the page itself (of course). So the flow is like: dashboard page -> click Add Education link -> Add Education page displayed -> user tries to submit form but misses some required inputs -> error messages appear under missed inputs -> user clicks to go back to dashboard (i.e. abandons adding new education details) -> user clicks again on Add Education link -> Add Education page displays STILL with errors. I can open a new question for this?

Comment: Thanks for your help @thedude I created a new question re. error display: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62696296/react-redux-resetting-errors-when-a-page-loads

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `useEffect` hook with `props` as one of the dependencies.

EDIT:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (props.errors) 
            setEduState({ errors: props.errors });
    },
    [props]
);
```

I believe your current useEffect would lead to an infinite rerendering since you are consistently setting the eduState and eduState as one of your dependencies as well.

Comment: I used useEffect(
    props.errors => {
      setEduState({
        ...eduState,
        errors: props.errors
      });
    },
    [props]
  ); but I get this error: Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," on the =>

Comment: Also, would this not cause infinite re-renders, since the props are changing every time useEffect is called?

Comment: I'm sorry about that. You're not supposed to receive an argument in the useEffect function. The useEffect hook will only run everytime the props changes. It would not lead to infinite re-renders since you're only changing the local state of the component

Answer (score 1):

change

```
  setEduState({
      ...eduState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
```

and

```
setEduState({  ...eduState, errors: props.errors }
```

you have overwriten your state, dont do that :D

Comment: Thanks, I see that now, I was replacing the eduState object with just the error